# Parse: cURL HTTP Post

Tags: parsing, ssl, curl, certificate

I am posting using cURL to Parse (www.parse.com).  They have a REST that allows me to manage certain things through POSTS and GETS.

However, I receive the following reply:

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

I am using JSON validated by JSONLint.com.  My app ID and rest key are correct - I believe it has something to do with the lack of certificate I'm providing to cURL.  I've read a few threads on using cURL on Windows:

http://richardwarrender.com/2007/05/the-secret-to-curl-in-php-on-windows/

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

so I downloaded the .pem file they suggest and used --cacert in my request to the same effect.

Should I have a certificate from www.parse.com?  Thanks!

Comment: A few months ago I had a case where it wasn't my certificate, but my certificate's parent that was the problem.  Have you checked that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by parent?  I've tried wiping my certificates and re-getting them, but that had the same effect.

Comment: To follow up on Yzmir's comment, the `--cacert cacerts.pem` option points curl at a file of certificates that define a "chain" that curl will use to validate the certificate provided by the host you are querying is valid. So, if the host provides certificate A, and B is the signer of A, you need to put B in `cacerts.pem`. Furthermore, if C is the signer of B, put C in `cacerts.pem`. And so on until you get to a cert that is its own signer (which you also put in `cacerts.pem`, but now you can stop).